# Why were Ctrl-Z and Ctrl-Y chosen as undo/redo shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, internationalisation, keyboard-layout

Is there a reason why some keyboard shortcuts are chosen?

Specifically, <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>. Sometimes I happen to switch from a QWERTY keyboard to a QWERTZ keyboard. Apart from the time it takes to adapt to the new layout, the most frustrating thing (at least for me) is that the "**undo**" and "**redo**" commands are inverted.

Usually shortcuts are chosen based on the first letter of the command (e.g., <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> for printing). Is it possible that no one has considered this problem in this case?

Comment: Well, I assume that the people who made these standards wanted to keep the ctrl commands close together on the keyboard; e.g. ctrl z, x, c, v. When they ran out of space, they used uncommon letters (like, what command starts with a y?) Some keyboards have ctrl-shift-z as redo, keep in mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It is likely based on the key position of other commonly used actions (cut, copy, paste) on the keyboard.**

> Likely it all boils down to placement on a QWERTY keyboard.
>
> [...]
>
> From there, X and V are just adjacent keys, for Cut and Paste. It's
>   simple to remember where they are, and you'll build up muscle memory
>   if they're close. (You'll do it even if they aren't, but if they're
>   adjacent, it helps.) Eventually, when Mac and Windows word processors
>   (and other applications) started offering Undo as a feature, putting
>   them together still makes a kind of conceptual sense: these are basic
>   document editing features which work the same way across even very
>   different applications ("Undo" is undo in Word, or Adobe Illustrator,
>   for example, even if the content types are wildly different).

Source: [Why was 'Z' chosen for the CTRL+Z/CMD+Z shortcut?](https://www.quora.com/Why-was-Z-chosen-for-the-CTRL+Z-CMD+Z-shortcut)

It's also close to the control/command key, which makes it easy to use with one hand. Common actions (cut, copy, paste, undo) are used a lot, so it is important to have them close to the control/command key.